# convert a ruby array into an R array (within an R list) for RinRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, r

I've created a rails API that wraps an R algorithm in ruby using RinRuby.

The parameters required by the R algorithm are passed as an R list, which is comprised of strings, numbers and arrays.

I'm able to pass the list into the R algorithm using RinRuby, if there are not arrays in the list, by generating a CSV.  But when there are arrays within the list, the arrays are converted into a string.  I can't figure out a way to convert a ruby array into an R array within the converted list.

Here is the RinRuby code that calls the R algorithm:

```
def algorithm
    R.eval <<-EOF
        list <- get_algorithm(#{mapped_filter_values_to_csv}, #{mapped_filter_names})
        result = toJSON(list)
    EOF
end
```

Here is the method that creates the list:

```
def mapped_filter_values_to_csv
    "list(#{CSV.generate_line(converted_filter_values.map{|filter_value| map_individual_value filter_value}, :row_sep=>"")})"
end
```

Here is the map_individual_value method (called by the previous method):

```
def map_individual_value filter_value
    if filter_value.class == Array
        "c(#{CSV.generate_line(filter_value, :row_sep=>"")})"
    elsif filter_value.class == String
        "\'#{filter_value}\'"
    else
        filter_value
    end
end
```

Here is an example of what is happening currently, with "c(1,9)" as a string in R:

```
list <- get_algorithm(list("c(1,9)",'M', 1), c("filter1", "filter2", "filter3"))
```

Here is what I need to happen, with c(1,9) as an R array:

```
list <- get_algorithm(list(c(1,9),'M', 1), c("filter1", "filter2", "filter3"))`enter code here`
```

Any ideas how to convert a ruby array into an R array?

Thanks!

Comment: This is because you're using CSV.generate_line, and in CSV individual bare elements are not allowed to contain commas. Thus, in order to accurately represent your input, it quotes the whole thing. Keep in mind that in CSV, without the quotes, you'd have a list with four elements: `c(1`, `9)`, `'M'`, and `1`.

This leaves me the question of why you're using CSV in the first place. I'm not familiar with R, but I think you're just making things harder on yourself by converting to an unrelated and inappropriate data format.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that CSV is its own data format and has very specific rules about where commas are allowed to go. It also doesn't understand parentheses. As far as CSV is concerned, without the quotes your original list would have had four elements: `c(1`, `9)`, `'M'`, and `1`. To avoid that, `c(1,9)` gets quoted, because that's how CSV works.

Much easier to avoid CSV entirely and construct the string representation yourself using join and map:

```
def mapped_filter_values_to_csv
  values = converted_filter_values.map{|filter_value| map_individual_value filter_value}
  "list(#{ values.join(',') })"
end

def map_individual_value filter_value
  if filter_value.class == Array
    values = filter_value.map {|v| map_individual_value(v) }
    "c(#{values.join(',')})"
  elsif filter_value.class == String
    "\'#{filter_value}\'"
  else
    filter_value
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The reason I'm using CSV is because I need the values to be comma separated and to keep their type (eg: list('M', 1)).  If I join the values then it passes a string to the list: list("M, 1"), which is not a valid argument for the R algorithm.  So, the CSV generation works at the list level, but when I try to use the CSV to convert from a ruby array to an R array (within the list) I have to use string interpolation and the whole thing gets passed as a string (eg "c(1,9)").  If I use your approach I get: "c('1,9')" and what I want to get is c(1,9).

Comment: Can you give an example of the return value of `converted_filter_values`, then?  I'm expecting it to be `[[1,9], "M", 1]`. If it is, then the return value of `mapped_filter_values_to_csv` is exactly `"list(c(1,9),'M',1)"` in my test.

Comment: Also, in CSV everything is a string. Anything that appears to "keep it's type" does so by coincidence, because CSV doesn't know anything about either Ruby types or R types. Even the Ruby standard library's CSV generator doesn't know about Ruby types, it just calls "to_s" on everything it's going to put in to the CSV, then checks to see if the resulting string contains any reserved characters. If it doesn't, it puts it in as-is, and if it does, it puts it in surrounded by quotes (it does a bit more, but not much).

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right, the return value of converted_filter_values is: [[1,9], "M", 1].  I get the same thing as you in ruby: "list(c(1,9),'M',1)" but when that's passed to R it turns into this: "list('c(1,9)','M',1)" :/.  It's confusing that it works for the mapped_filter_values_to_csv and not map_individual_value.  But based on what you said about how the CSV generation I guess I should feel lucky that at least one thing worked.

Comment: @erica In that case, I would recommend two things: First, try simplifying your code down to the bare minimum, with nothing dynamic at all, and make sure that `R.eval(%q{list <- get_algorithm(list(c(1,9),'M', 1), c("filter1", "filter2", "filter3"))})` actually works. If not, then RinRuby is actively transforming your submitted source in ways I, not being an R user, am not going to be able to predict. You'll have to ask the RinRuby maintainers directly, or look at the source.

Comment: If `R.eval` _does_ work when passed a string literal with the structure you're aiming for, try replacing your inline `R.eval <<-EOF ... EOF` with `src = <<-EOF ... EOF`, `puts src`, `R.eval src`, to make sure the final string getting passed to R.eval really has the structure you want. If `puts src` there shows `list('c(1,9)','M',1)`, then that's a problem we can fix in Ruby-land, which means it's one I can probably help with.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it. I think it was something going on with RinRuby, so I threw in the towel and ended up just dealing with it on the R side.  I'll let you know if I find a better solution some day :)